# open .csv files with in-place excel in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, excel, ole

If I open an .xls file from eclipse it opens using excel embedded in eclipse, however if I open a .csv file it opens excel as a separate application.  How do I configure eclipse to use the in-place ole editor for .csv files?

Answer (score 3):

Try Window > Preferences > Editors > File Associations and associate your file extension *.csv to the built-in ole editor in Eclipse.